# How to put file to app private folder?

Tags: android, android-external-storage

My app will embed some mp3 songs

Currently I put mp3 to raw folder and use this method to play

```
MediaPlayer p= new MediaPlayer();
public void playMusic(String file){
    Uri uri=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/"+file);
    if(uri!=null) {
        p.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        try {
            p.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            p.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        p.start();
    }
}
```

If file in raw folder, I cannot delete, rename, list, make sub-folder in the app

How to put files in app private folder, then I can use `getExternalFilesDir` to access these files?

Comment: did you check the following link :- http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/File/CreateaUriforfilesonexternalstorage.htm , hope it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, *private folder* and *getExternalFilesDir*
are the opposite.

You're already doing the right I think.

You have to be aware of the following :

- embedded resources are static and immutables. Like drawables, values, strings, etc. you can store your data in a raw directory but, during run-time, you'll not be able to modified them
- dynamic or *in-live* resources are stored where you want, [see storage guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

By the way, you can embed resources in raw directory and, at first launch for example, store these data in internal storage.

Comment: May be I get wrong, please forget `private folder`, I want to put some file to app folder, like ios `/private/var/mobile/Applications/UUID/Documents`

Comment: You mean _internal storage_ ? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage#filesInternal

Comment: Yes, I need include all files in apk, and my app provide a function to delete these files, if file in `raw`, I cannot delete file

Comment: You cannot delete embedded resources